# Using tapply with multiple categories is not working

Tags: r, tapply

I am trying to use `tapply` in R so that it gives me a summary of averages for data that correspond to two categories (category_name and brand_name)

It is working fine when I include one category, i.e.:

```
brandavg <- tapply(train$price, train$brand_name, mean)
head(brandavg, 10)
```

Looks something like:

```
""               "brandavg"    "brandstd"
"% Pure"          13.85         5.53719480565651
"10.Deep"         21            NA
"21men"           10            NA
```

But when I try to run it with two categories, using this code:

```
brandcatavg <- tapply(train$price, list(train$brand_name, train$category_name), mean)
head(brandcatavg, 10)
```

I get along list of category names (far more than 10!), but no averages.

I'm sure this has a really easy solution that I'm missing, but I'm hitting my head on the wall trying to figure it out.

Current code attempts have been:

```
brandcatavg <- tapply(train$price, list(train$brand_name, train$category_name), mean)

brandcatavg <- with(train, tapply(price, list(brand_name, category_name), mean))
```

Both yield something that looks like:

```
Vintage & Collectibles/Paper Ephemera/Postcard Vintage & Collectibles/Paper Ephemera/Stamps
                 Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Bowl Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Casserole
                 Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Cream and Sugar Set Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Dinnerware Set
                 Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Flatware Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Glassware
                 Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Mug Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Other
                 Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Pitcher Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Plate
                 Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Salt and Pepper Shakers Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Teacup
                 Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Teapot Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Tray
                 Vintage & Collectibles/Serving/Tumbler Vintage & Collectibles/Supplies/Bead
```

(Note that I cut the output for length...)

When I pull the first 10 columns it looks like:

```
   train_id                                   name item_condition_id                                      category_name
```

1         0    MLB Cincinnati Reds T Shirt Size XL                 3                                  Men/Tops/T-shirts
2         1       Razer BlackWidow Chroma Keyboard                 3 Electronics/Computers & Tablets/Components & Parts
3         2                         AVA-VIV Blouse                 1                        Women/Tops & Blouses/Blouse
4         3                  Leather Horse Statues                 1               Home/Home DÃ©cor/Home DÃ©cor Accents
5         4                   24K GOLD plated rose                 1                            Women/Jewelry/Necklaces
6         5       Bundled items requested for Ruie                 3                                  Women/Other/Other
7         6     Acacia pacific tides santorini top                 3                           Women/Swimwear/Two-Piece
8         7   Girls cheer and tumbling bundle of 7                 3                    Sports & Outdoors/Apparel/Girls
9         8                  Girls Nike Pro shorts                 3                    Sports & Outdoors/Apparel/Girls
10        9 Porcelain clown doll checker pants VTG                 3           Vintage & Collectibles/Collectibles/Doll
        brand_name price shipping
1                     10        1
2            Razer    52        0
3           Target    10        1
4                     35        1
5                     44        0
6                     59        0
7  Acacia Swimwear    64        0
8            Soffe     6        1
9             Nike    19        0
10                     8        0
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            item_description
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         No description yet
2                                                                                                               This keyboard is in great condition and works like it came out of the box. All of the ports are tested and work perfectly. The lights are customizable via the Razer Synapse app on your PC.
3                                                                                                                                                                               Adorable top with a hint of lace and a key hole in the back! The pale pink is a 1X, and I also have a 3X available in white!
4                                                                                                                              New with tags. Leather horses. Retail for [rm] each. Stand about a foot high. They are being sold as a pair. Any questions please ask. Free shipping. Just got out of storage
5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  Complete with certificate of authenticity
6                                                                                                                                                                                                     Banana republic bottoms, Candies skirt with matching blazer,Amy Byers suit, Loft bottoms and cami top.
7                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Size small but straps slightly shortened to fit xs, besides that, perfect condition
8                               You get three pairs of Sophie cheer shorts size small and medium girls and two sports bra/boy shorts spandex matching sets in small and medium girls. All items total retail for [rm] in store and you can take him today for less than the price of one item at the store!)
9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Girls Size small Plus green. Three shorts total.
10 I realized his pants are on backwards after the picture. They were very dirty so I hand washed them. He has a stuffed body and painted porcelain head, hands and feet. Back before clowns were too scary. 9" tall. No chips or cracks but minor paint loss in a few places. Clown Circus Doll Collectible

(dput is giving me funky results.)

Eventually got this to work with the code:

library(dplyr)

```
brandcatavg <- train %>%
    group_by(category_name, brand_name) %>%
    summarise(averageprice = mean(price, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: I cant see anything obviously wrong in your code ; could you add a small example of your data as perhaps there is something specific to that. You can do this by editing your question with the results of `dput(droplevels(train[1:10, c("price", "brand_name", "category_name")]))`

Comment: Definitely. I've edited above to show more code!

Comment: Julia. Please can you add the data in the form that is returned from using `dput` - this allows users to easily copy and paste it into their r session. As it is , it will take a bit of effort for users to make your data usable.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, 
Try:

```
with(train, tapply(price, list(brand_name, category_name), mean))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, I seem to be getting the same error when using this code that I was before (essentially a very long list of categories without the means)

Comment: Could you provide 5 or 6 lines of data. Also, there are other packages `dplyr`, `reshape2` for this type of problems. I can try on my end!

Comment: Definitely! I've edited above to show a few lines of data!

Comment: @JuliaNolan Is it in a csv file? Text file? do `head(df)`. Here is a link, this is a sample, how to copy paste from R. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176460/how-to-paste-data-from-r-to-stackoverflow